# optimize complex sql query with group by and having

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having troubles with a query that is too slow (about 2-3 minutes!).

the complete query is

```sql
SELECT Count(DISTINCT activitytr0_.libraryid) AS col_0_0_
FROM   mma_activitytrackerlibrary activitytr0_
       inner join mma_activitytracker activities1_
               ON activitytr0_.libraryid = activities1_.libraryid
WHERE  ( activitytr0_.channel NOT IN ( 'Classica', 'VOD Contents', 'FOX' ) )
       AND ( activities1_.phase IN ( 'Quality control', 'Spot check' ) )
       AND ( activities1_.result NOT IN ( 'Fail', 'TBC' ) )
       AND ( activitytr0_.tx_date IS NULL
              OR activitytr0_.tx_date >= DATE '2020-07-13' )
       AND ( activitytr0_.ident_tx IN (SELECT channelsch3_.clipid
                                       FROM   mma_channelscheduleevents channelsch3_
                                       GROUP  BY channelsch3_.clipid
                                       HAVING Min(channelsch3_.eventstarttime) >= DATE '2020-07-13')
              OR ( activitytr0_.tx_date IS NULL
                   AND activitytr0_.ident_tx NOT IN (SELECT channelsch4_.clipid
                                                     FROM   mma_channelscheduleevents channelsch4_) ) )
       AND activitytr0_.trash <> 'Y'
```

"cutting" the query, the slowest part is this:

```sql
SELECT channelsch3_.clipid
FROM   mma_channelscheduleevents channelsch3_
GROUP  BY channelsch3_.clipid
HAVING Min(channelsch3_.eventstarttime) >= DATE '2020-07-13')
```

this query takes about 21 seconds, on a table with ~46000000 rows, with indexes on the `clipid` and on the `eventstarttime` fields, and returns about 2000 rows

keep in mind that this is a subquery that is part of a `field not in (...)` clause

I don't know how to optimize the query, keep in mind that `clipid` can be duplicated, and I want only the `clipid`s where there is not even one associated  `eventstarttime` in the "past"

so, for this simple example

```
+--------+----------------+
| clipid | eventstarttime |
+--------+----------------+
| A      | 2020-01-01     |
| A      | 2021-01-01     |
| B      | 2020-01-01     |
| C      | 2021-01-01     |
+--------+----------------+
```

I want only one row, with `C`

--- as requested by Sayan Malakshinov

```sql
select * from user_tab_col_statistics where table_name='MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS'
```

returns

```
TABLE_NAME               |COLUMN_NAME            |NUM_DISTINCT|LOW_VALUE  |HIGH_VALUE |DENSITY|NUM_NULLS|NUM_BUCKETS|LAST_ANALYZED      |SAMPLE_SIZE|GLOBAL_STATS|USER_STATS|AVG_COL_LEN|HISTOGRAM|
-------------------------|-----------------------|------------|-----------|-----------|-------|---------|-----------|-------------------|-----------|------------|----------|-----------|---------|
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTID                |           1|ÅT  ]4     |ÅT  ]4     |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          7|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEID             |           1|Â Z        |Â Z        |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          4|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTTYPE              |           1|           |           |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          2|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTSTARTTIME         |           1|xx         |xx         |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          8|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTENDTIME           |           1|xx         |xx         |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          8|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTACTUALSTARTFRAMES |           1|Ä =        |Ä =        |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          4|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTSECEVENTOFFSET    |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|CLIPID                 |           1|THL50883   |THL50883   |      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |          9|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SEGMENTNUMBER          |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEDTITLE         |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEDSOM           |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEDDURATION      |           1|00:00:00:00|00:00:00:00|      1|        0|          1|2020-07-13 22:00:08|          1|YES         |NO        |         12|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEDDURATIONFRAMES|           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|EVENTCONTROLCODES      |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|RECONCILEKEY           |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEDSOMBCD        |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS|SCHEDULEDDURATIONBCD   |           0|           |           |      0|        1|          0|2020-07-13 22:00:08|           |YES         |NO        |          0|NONE     |
```

Comment: Please provide your complete query. Optimizing sub query alone will not help

Comment: @JimMacaulay I understand your point, but this query is already too slow as is

Comment: can you provide an explain plan for the slow group by query ?

Comment: 21s from 2-3 minutes is not big part. Show us real(not explain) plan with statistics please. And also `select * from user_tab_col_statistics where table_name='MMA_CHANNELSCHEDULEEVENTS'`

Comment: @VitoDeTullio table statistics shows that you have just 1 clipid... is it really actual statistics? I see it was gathered 2020-07-13 22:00:08, but is this table is really so small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't optimize your original query, since you didn't show it and we do not know real execution plan with statistics, but I can suggest you one way to improve those part that you showed us:

1. You need to create index on (eventstarttime, clipid)
2. You the query like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.clipid
FROM mma_channelscheduleevents c
WHERE c.eventstarttime>=date'2020-07-13'
and   not exists (select 1
                  from mma_channelscheduleevents c2
                  where c2.clipid = c.clipid and c2.eventstarttime < date'2020-07-13'
                 );
```

It should be much faster in case if the number of rows with `eventstarttime>=date'2020-07-13'` is far less then number of rows `eventstarttime<date'2020-07-13'`.

Comment: this query is actually faster that the original... in my test it takes about 8seconds instead of the 20

Comment: @VitoDeTullio great, so will you mark my answer as correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

You might find that it is faster to filter before aggregating.  So it is worth trying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.clipid
FROM mma_channelscheduleevents c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mma_channelscheduleevents c2
                  WHERE c2.clipid = c.clipid AND c2.eventstarttime)  DATE '2020-07-13'
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `mma_channelscheduleevents(clip_id, eventstarttime)`.

This is worth a try.  I'm not certain it will be any better, though.

EDIT:

Presumably, you have another table of "clips".  If so, I recommend:

```
SELECT cl.clipid
FROM clips cl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mma_channelscheduleevents c2
                  WHERE c2.clipid = cl.clipid AND
                        c2.eventstarttime < DATE '2020-07-13'
                 );
```

Comment: should be `c2.eventstarttime < DATE '2020-07-13'`

Comment: unfortunately the query is almost twice as slow as the original one (~45 seconds). I also created the index but I saw no changes in the timing

Comment: @VitoDeTullio . . . If you have a separate table of "clips", then the fastest method is probably to use that table.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov . . . Than you.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov the idea is good, but no, I don't have a "clips" table